# Polymer 1.0, How to implement Infinite nested dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I have following JSON obj,

```
    categoryList = [{
    "title": "Computers",
    "categories": 
    [
      {
        "title": "Laptops",
        "categories": 
        [
          {
            "title": "Ultrabooks",
            "categories": 
            [
              {
                "title": "Lenovo",
                "categories": 
                [
                  {
                    "title": "i5 intel"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "Dell"
          },
          {
            "title": "Macbooks",
            "categories": 
            [
              {
                "title": "Air"
              }, 
              {
                "title": "Pro"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "title": "Desktops"
      }, 
      {
        "title": "Tablets",
        "categories": 
        [
          {
            "title": "Apple"
          }, 
          {
            "title": "Android"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "title": "Printers"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

As you can see, each categories could have a child categories so it could literally go on forever. I am trying to display all of them but I can't figure out how I would do this.

This is all I have so far (obviously this only gets the first child in each categories):

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{categoryList}}" as="category">  
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{_hasData(category.categories)}}">
      <div>{{category.title}}</div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{category.categories}}" as="item">
         <div>{{item.title}}</div>
      </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Your `categories` object is malformed, so that would need to be fixed before your binding would even be processed.

Comment: I've changed your Json object for now, but please be careful in future as it creates lot of problem for other people who try to help.

Comment: yeah, while formatting JSON, it all messed up, however thank u for ur help @a1626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `recursive code` here.
[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/MkKHfLeZ08nsaFAWMgJt) a plunker for same.

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="infinite-repeat">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items={{categories}} as="category">
      <div>{{category.title}}</div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{category.categories}}" as="item">
        <div>{{item.title}}</div>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{_hasData(item.categories)}}">
          <infinite-repeat categories={{item.categories}}></infinite-repeat>
        </template>
      </template>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'infinite-repeat',
    properties: {
      categories: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return [{
            "title": "Computers",
            "categories": [{
              "title": "Laptops",
              "categories": [{
                "title": "Ultrabooks",
                "categories": [{
                  "title": "Lenovo",
                  "categories": [{
                    "title": "i5 intel"
                  }]
                }]
              }, {
                "title": "Dell"
              }, {
                "title": "Macbooks",
                "categories": [{
                  "title": "Air"
                }, {
                  "title": "Pro"
                }]
              }]
            }, {
              "title": "Desktops"
            }, {
              "title": "Tablets",
              "categories": [{
                "title": "Apple"
              }, {
                "title": "Android"
              }]
            }, {
              "title": "Printers"
            }]
          }];
        }
      }
    },
    _hasData: function(item) {
      return item && item.length > 0;
    }
  })
</script>

<infinite-repeat></infinite-repeat>
```